# JAX-RS service too slow

Tags: java, performance

In my project, I am using JAX-RS(websphere), EJB and OpenJPA as major technologies.

Even in a very simple scenario of simple GET calls, service takes quite long. Major tasks I can see involved are DB call using JPA,converting entity object to a transfer object using Dozer mapper, and finally underlying websphere implementation converting transfer object to JSON. Data is just few rows in table with no eager loading(thus no data from table other than target table).

I don't think huge computation involved here. Still it is taking around 10-12 seconds. Also server is powerful enough.

What should be my approach to find out the root cause? I plan to find out time consumed by each major component involved using System.nanoTime(). But are there any other better approaches?

Answer (score 0):

This is what we had done when we had such issues earlier.
We analyzed and found the major bottlenecks, most of the times few incorrect parameters/ method choices result in such bottlenecks.
So try using alternatives for the methods that are consuming most of your time.

You don't need to use system.nanotime. You can use any profiler tool like virtualVM, that would give you a detailed analysis of the time taken every single unit.

Comment: Thanks for inputs. JProfiler seems to be most commonly used tool. Which one would you suggest?

Comment: Jprofiler is paid I think, so I didn't suggest it. We used JRockit earlier, but looks like its no more supported. They merged it in HotspotVM. VisualVM is oracles project, so I am assuming they would be using some of functionalities from jrockit.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may not answer your question directly. But you can use jvisualVM to find the root cause. Below blog will help you to configure it on your eclipse quickly 
[https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2013/05/setting-up-visualvm-in-under-5-minutes/](http://scn.sap.com/community/java/blog/2015/09/18/step-by-step-to-use-visualvm-to-do-performance-measurement)

**jvisualVM is the tool comes free with jdk , you can spot it in the bin folder of the jdk with the name "jvisualvm.exe" you can just double click on it to start**

Once you configured run your program then let VisualVM capture your processing. then you could interpret which class spend more CPU or time consumption by clicking "Sampler -> CPU " button, That will give you which method takes more time and CPU.Below blog will also help you to analyze the data.

http://scn.sap.com/community/java/blog/2015/09/18/step-by-step-to-use-visualvm-to-do-performance-measurement

**If your program spends most of the time in networking related packages, then either your program is waiting for the response from the server or your program is calling the server more often in side a loop (In this case you have to find a way to aggregate the data request so that call to the external server will be reduced)**
Please keep us posted about your findings!